# How can I change Activity with an Intent that is located in different folder?

Tags: android, android-activity

The structure of my project is as

```
-src
    -folder1
         Activity1.java
         otherfiles.java
     -folder2
         `Activity2.java
```

Now my question: How can I call Activity2 from Activity1?

```
       Intent myintent = new Intent(getContext(), ** Activity2.class** ) // <<--
```

Did not work :)

Comment: what is the error ? can u post logs ?

Answer (score 1):

Intent myintent = new Intent(getContext(), your.folder.path.Activity2 )

Comment: Thanks. But it does not take the path. Says, error.

in   bin/mytest/folder1   there is Activity1.class
in   bin/mytest/folder2   there is Activity2.class

The system takes the first part of the path automatically,

error says "mytest.folder1/mytest.folder2.Activity2" not found!

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can fix that by changing the declaration of your activity in AndroidManifest file. You need to do something like this :

```
<activity android:name="com.android.examples.activities.Activity2" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
            </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

`com.android.examples.activities.Activity2` - is the name of package where your class is

And after that you just call your activity like :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Activity1.this, Activity2.class);
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution: In activity1, import activity2.

For example, I faced the same issue where my loginactivity and accountpasswordActivity where in different directories.

```
import com.chiguruecospace.chiguru_mobile_app.loginactivity;
```

I added this code in my accountpasswordActivity and it worked.

[File Hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rYVYn.png)